# How to save web page as image using python

Tags: python, web, screenshot

I am using python to create a "favorites" section of a website.  Part of what I want to do is grab an image to put next to their link.  So the process would be that the user puts in a URL and I go grab a screenshot of that page and display it next to the link.  Easy enough?

I have currently downloaded [pywebshot](http://www.coderholic.com/pywebshot-generate-website-thumbnails-using-python/) and it works great from my terminal on my local box.  However, when I put it on the server, I get a Segmentation Fault with the following traceback:

```
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:57: GtkWarning: could not open display
  warnings.warn(str(e), _gtk.Warning)
./pywebshot.py:16: Warning: invalid (NULL) pointer instance
  self.parent = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
./pywebshot.py:16: Warning: g_signal_connect_data: assertion `G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
  self.parent = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
./pywebshot.py:49: GtkWarning: Screen for GtkWindow not set; you must always set
a screen for a GtkWindow before using the window
  self.parent.show_all()
./pywebshot.py:49: GtkWarning: gdk_screen_get_default_colormap: assertion `GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
  self.parent.show_all()
./pywebshot.py:49: GtkWarning: gdk_colormap_get_visual: assertion `GDK_IS_COLORMAP (colormap)' failed
  self.parent.show_all()
./pywebshot.py:49: GtkWarning: gdk_screen_get_root_window: assertion `GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
  self.parent.show_all()
./pywebshot.py:49: GtkWarning: gdk_window_new: assertion `GDK_IS_WINDOW (parent)' failed
  self.parent.show_all()
Segmentation fault
```

I know that some things can't run in a pts environment, but honestly that's a little beyond me right now.  If I need to somehow pretend that my pts connection is tty, I can try it.  But at this point I'm not even sure what's going on and I admit it's a bit over my head.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Also, if there's a web service that I can pass a url and receive an image, that would work just as well.  I am NOT married to the idea of pywebshot.

I do know that the server I'm on is running X and has all the necessary python modules installed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you start script on you server? Do you connect via ssh or VNC?

Comment: right now i'm using SSH, but it'll eventually be kicked off by Apache when the user saves their shortcut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [websnapr.com](http://websnapr.com) which is a web service that will give you the image with just a little bit of work.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(['wget', '-O', MYFILENAME+'.png', 'http://images.websnapr.com/?url='+MYURL+'&size=s&nocache=82']).wait()
```

Easy as pie.

Comment: however, this way you get websnapr watermark on the obtained image. Any other ideas to get unadulterated image snapshots of webpages?

Comment: @anu.agg a good example for a whole page screenshot is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58068662/2149425

Comment: tho use of an external webservice is not appropriate.  It should be local python code only.

Answer (score 2):

This is the code I used to get the screenshot of the whole scrolled webpage:

```
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import logging
import os
import time

# Set default download folder for ChromeDriver
videos_folder = r"./download"
if not os.path.exists(videos_folder):
    os.makedirs(videos_folder)
prefs = {"download.default_directory": videos_folder}

def open_url(address):
    # SELENIUM SETUP
    logging.getLogger('WDM').setLevel(logging.WARNING)  # just to hide not so rilevant webdriver-manager messages
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.headless = True
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=chrome_options)
    driver.implicitly_wait(1)
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.get(address)
    driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)  # to set the screenshot width
    save_screenshot(driver, '{}/Screenshot.png'.format(videos_folder))
    driver.quit()

def save_screenshot(driver, file_name):
    height, width = scroll_down(driver)
    driver.set_window_size(width, height)
    img_binary = driver.get_screenshot_as_png()
    img = Image.open(BytesIO(img_binary))
    img.save(file_name)
    # print(file_name)
    print("Screenshot saved!")

def scroll_down(driver):
    total_width = driver.execute_script("return document.body.offsetWidth")
    total_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.parentNode.scrollHeight")
    viewport_width = driver.execute_script("return document.body.clientWidth")
    viewport_height = driver.execute_script("return window.innerHeight")

    rectangles = []

    i = 0
    while i < total_height:
        ii = 0
        top_height = i + viewport_height

        if top_height > total_height:
            top_height = total_height

        while ii < total_width:
            top_width = ii + viewport_width

            if top_width > total_width:
                top_width = total_width

            rectangles.append((ii, i, top_width, top_height))

            ii = ii + viewport_width

        i = i + viewport_height

    previous = None
    part = 0

    for rectangle in rectangles:
        if not previous is None:
            driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo({0}, {1})".format(rectangle[0], rectangle[1]))
            time.sleep(0.5)
        # time.sleep(0.2)

        if rectangle[1] + viewport_height > total_height:
            offset = (rectangle[0], total_height - viewport_height)
        else:
            offset = (rectangle[0], rectangle[1])

        previous = rectangle

    return total_height, total_width

open_url("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091940/how-to-save-web-page-as-image-using-python")
```

Here the screenshot obtained:

[image: Whole webpage screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

```
from selenium import webdriver    
from xvfbwrapper import Xvfb
d=Xvfb(width=400,height=400)
d.start()
browser=webdriver.Firefox()
url="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091940/how-to-save-web-page-as-image-using-python"
browser.get(url)
destination="screenshot_filename.jpg"
if browser.save_screenshot(destination):
    print "File saved in the destination filename"
browser.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me guess, the server does not have an X server, right?

You may have to run a headless X server to get this working.

Comment: My server does have X running.

Comment: Seems like some GTK component is lacking on the X session. Could you run X as the user that runs the script and start it from xterm?